# How to push a key/ value into JSON objects

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to push a Id into a Json array of objects. Every object must have '"JobId" : Value' inserted before it is sent to the apiController. I am trying to use a forEach loop for this but I am stuck. Right now instead of inserting this in the each object in the array it is inserting at the end of the array. I have a plunkr setup. 
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tVxFLzHJ9zKgNZiS7HN4?p=preview)

```
$scope.array = [{
  ESOURCELINEID:"5464",
  QBRFQLINESUPPLIERPARTNUMBER:"HW12",
  QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUOM:"ft"
}, {
  ESOURCELINEID:"8569",
  QBRFQLINESUPPLIERPARTNUMBER:"LT34",
  QBRFQLINESUPPLIERQUOTEUOM:"Meter"
}];

var JobId = 143;
$scope.array.forEach(function (newJobItem) {
    $scope.array.push({'JobId' : JobId});
});

var index = 0;
$scope.array.forEach(function (newJobItem) {
    console.log('newJobItem #' + (index++) + ': ' + JSON.stringify(newJobItem));
});
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you're doing is iterating over each item via `$scope.array.forEach` but then you're not actually modifying the item that is returned from the callback `newJobItem` but just pushing a new item: `$scope.array.push({'JobId' : JobId});`.

The correct line inside your forEach should be `newJobItem.JobId = JobId;`. That way you're modifying the existing entries inside `$scope.array` instead of just pushing new objects.

More explicitly:

```
$scope.array.forEach(function (newJobItem) {
    $scope.array.push({'JobId' : JobId});
});
```

Becomes:

```
$scope.array.forEach(function (newJobItem) {
    newJobItem.JobId = JobId;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case i need it as an array. So you can use this with the brackets: `$scope.array.push({[JobId]:Job[JobId]});` Hope this will helps anyone also ...

Answer (score 4):

You want to manipulate the objects in the array, not the array itself. Try this:

```
$scope.array.forEach(function (newJobItem) { 
   var JobId = 143;
   newJobItem.JobId = JobId;
});
```

Comment: up vote for being correct but a few minutes behind the first guy! thanks though